# Initially selected items in p:selectCheckboxMenu showing object reference instead of value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Good day. In my project, I have a List of custom objects which I use in my PrimeFaces `p:selectCheckboxMenu`. I use a converter for this class. The dropdown looks great and if I select an item from the list, the "chips" display correctly. However, if I load the selected list on initialization, the selected "chip" shows a class reference (com.test.Characteristic@56e76bff) instead of the value of the object. I would expect it to show the return value of getAsString from the converter. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Example of what I am seeing]

On to the code for this:
**The custom object**

```
    public class Characteristic {
    public Characteristic() {
        super();
    }
    private String key;
    private String value;
    private String type;

    public Characteristic(String key, String value, String type) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

**The Converter:**

```
    @FacesConverter(value = "characteristicConverter")
    public class CharacteristicConverter implements Converter {
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
            return new Characteristic("testKey", value, "testType");
        }

        public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
            if (object == null) {
                return "";
            }
            if (object instanceof Characteristic) {
                Characteristic cha = (Characteristic) object;
                String name = cha.getValue();
                System.out.println("In the converter. Returning " + name);                
                return name;
            } else {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(object + " is not a Characteristic"));
            }
        }
    }
```

The System.out.prinln's in the converter display this when run:

*In the converter. Returning char1value*

*In the converter. Returning char2value*

*In the converter. Returning char3value*

*In the converter. Returning char1value*

**The Bean:**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "checkboxView")
public class CheckboxView {

    private List<Characteristic> allChars;
    private List<Characteristic> selectedChars;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        allChars = new ArrayList<Characteristic>();
        allChars.add(new Characteristic("char1key","char1value","test"));
        allChars.add(new Characteristic("char2key","char2value","test"));
        allChars.add(new Characteristic("char3key","char3value","test"));
        selectedChars = new ArrayList<Characteristic>();
        selectedChars.add(new Characteristic("char1key","char1value","test"));
    }

    public void setAllChars(List<Characteristic> allChars) {
        this.allChars = allChars;
    }

    public List<Characteristic> getAllChars() {
        return allChars;
    }

    public void setSelectedChars(List<Characteristic> selectedChars) {
        this.selectedChars = selectedChars;
    }

    public List<Characteristic> getSelectedChars() {
        return selectedChars;
    }
}
```

**The page:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="multiple" value="#{checkboxView.selectedChars}" label="Characteristics"
                                  multiple="true" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                                  converter="characteristicConverter">
                <f:selectItems value="#{checkboxView.allChars}" var="cha" itemLabel="#{cha.value}" itemValue="#{cha}"/>
            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does not using a filter make a difference? or not using multiple but e.g. the updateLabel? And what is your PF version?

Comment: @Kukeltje PrimeFaces version 6.1. I removed "filter" and "filterMatchMode" and I got the same string "com.test.Characteristic@56e76bff". If I remove multiple, it puts the value of label in the spot instead.  I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by updateLabel...

Comment: @Kukeltje I looked at the docs and added updateLabel="true" and I got the same bad result.

Comment: Can you (just for testing this issue) try 6.2 (good thing to always to, try the latest)

Comment: @Kukeltje It is the same with 6.2

Comment: Ohhh... but **what** did you assign initially? That is not visible in your code. Can you add that to make it a real [mcve]. And did you check if the converter was called in that case?

Comment: @Kukeltje I tried really hard to give a real, minimal, complete and verifiable example. "What did you assign initially?" that is in the bean in the init method. There are two lists which are hard coded; allChars and selectedChars. "did you check if the converter was called in that case" Yes, I put System.out.printlns in the converter and included the output in my original post.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the assignment in the init method...  And from the logging of the converter I did not explicitly see one of the lines was (as I understand now) from the 'assignment' part... Ok... Clear now and indeed a good [mcve]... Can you try something that I will quickly post as an answer (it is none but for formatting/clearity it is easier to abuse an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it has to do with comparing the Characteristics in the list with the pre-selected one (since in the visual list it is not selected either and it would most likely fail with an `h:selectManyCheckbox` as well). You can try changing

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    allChars = new ArrayList<Characteristic>();
    allChars.add(new Characteristic("char1key","char1value","test"));
    allChars.add(new Characteristic("char2key","char2value","test"));
    allChars.add(new Characteristic("char3key","char3value","test"));
    selectedChars = new ArrayList<Characteristic>();
    selectedChars.add(new Characteristic("char1key","char1value","test"));
}
```

to

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    allChars = new ArrayList<Characteristic>();
    Characteristic char1 = new Characteristic("char1key","char1value","test");
    Characteristic char2 = new Characteristic("char2key","char2value","test");
    Characteristic char3 = new Characteristic("char3key","char3value","test");
    allChars.add(char1);
    allChars.add(char2);
    allChars.add(char3);


    selectedChars = new ArrayList<Characteristic>();
    selectedChars.add(char1);
}
```

So the selected 'char1' is object wise identical to the one in the list. But even better would be to try to implement the equals and hash of the Characteristic explicitly.

Comment: So it IS the answer... Then I'd file an issue with PF that they should throw an error in this case. But you also fake things in your converter by creating a 'new Characteristic'... All dangerous things... But great it works (would have been a problem with a normal `h:selectManyCheckbox` as well btw... Give it a try what error you get then. PF should give the same error. (And did you check/run in development mode? Might be that you DO get an error then)

Comment: And see! A GOOD [mcve] helps finding causes more easily. Thank YOU for that and sorry for not directly seeing all... (a little more explit text could prevent this ;-))